# Matching the 1st satisfying inequality with 1 criteria & getting the column title

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

What I need is

1. `B` column values (red) should be calculated by Excel without VBA
2. `A` column (`Conf. Level`) has the criteria values per row
3. In each row, `B` column's related cell must print the 1st same row cell's column title that is >= than related criteria value

For example:

> B2 prints 0 since C2 is the 1st value that is >= than A2
>
> B3 prints 2 since E3 is the 1st value that is >= than A3

I've read the Q&A in this site with excel, indexing, match tags and tried something but I couldn't achieve more than #N/A. I've also read Microsoft excel help pages for `Index()` and `Match()` functions.

I have tons of rows in real case (not only 3 data rows).

Comment: Didn't you just post this exact question ?

Comment: Does your values in `C2:F2` always sorted?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes Tim, after achieving cumulative stuff, this was a new challenge for me :-(

Comment: @simoco yes, since those values are cumulative values of some other cells.

Comment: @TimWilliams EDIT: Oh, no, my previous question's scope was totally different, previous one was to get the cumulative values. This is to get the 1st one which is satisfying inequality.

Comment: My mistake - did not read this one fully ;-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one in `B2`:

```
=SMALL(IF(C2:F2>A2,$C$1:$F$1),1)
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula. Then drag formula down.

If there is no value greater than `A2`, `SMALL` returns `#NUM!`

Comment: +1 - This is nice because it works when the values are not sorted.

Comment: unfortunately I could understand nothing from your solution (too much elegant for my knowledge level) and only ate the fish you gave me, thank you so much, I finished my report just before exhausting.

Comment: it's easy! lets look at formula for `B3` - `=SMALL(IF(C3:F3>A3,$C$1:$F$1),1)`. Part `C3:F3>A3` returns array, e.g. `{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE}`. Next for `TRUE` values from this array this part `IF({FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE},$C$1:$F$1)` returns corresponding values from range `$C$1:$F$1`, e.g. `{FALSE,FALSE,2,3}`. And finally `SMALL({FALSE,FALSE,2,3},1)` returns first smallest value - `2`

Comment: @simoco kind regards for your explanation. I understood your solution after your explanation. It means that I was { 292 characters with spaces :-) } far away from learning to catch this type of fish.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were right to look at `INDEX` and `MATCH`. See if the following does what you intended:

[image]

The formula looks for a "match" with no type specified - that is, it will find the last value less than the value you are looking for (assuming that the values are sorted). You add `1` to get the value you intended (the first value not less than == the value that is greater or equal). It then uses `INDEX` to find the corresponding value (I used letters) in the row `C1:F1`, and returns that value in cell `B2` . If this is not what you intended, please clarify... it's what I understood from the question.

Obviously, if you need to repeat this formula many times, then write it in B2 as follows:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$F$1, MATCH(A2, C2:F2)+1)
```

and double-click the little "drag handle" in the bottom right hand corner to make it replicate to all rows in column B (whilst correctly preserving the absolute / relative addressing)

**EDIT** @Simoco pointed out that my formula would fail if the first value is larger than the criterion (since that means there is "no value smaller than"). You can tweak it with

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$F$1, MATCH(A2, C2:F2)+1),$C$1)
```

That's a really cool function that says "if the thing gives an error, use this other value instead". This does assume that there is at least one value that meets the criterion; if it is possible that none of the values meet the criterion you may need to be even smarter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$F$1, MATCH(A2, C2:F2)+1),IF(MAX(C2:F2)>A2,$C$1, "No match"))
```

That last error message can be whatever you want it to be, obviously.

Comment: seems that your formula won't work if _first_ value, i.e. `C2` greater than `A2`..

Comment: possible workground `=IF(C2>A2,$C$1,INDEX($C$1:$F$1, MATCH(A2, C2:F2)+1))` - not very elegant, but can't find better now

Comment: @simoco - I think I have a better workaround - but your solution is quite elegant, if a little harder to understand for an Excel novice (those array functions...). It's nice that it will work even for unsorted data. I think they are both valid approaches. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Personally I prefer your formula even despite the fact it's longer, since it's _not_ array formula:)

Comment: Floris, thank you for your help. I also tried your solution. It worked for >=2 cases however ıt doesn't work for 0 or 1 cases.

Comment: @AndreChenier thanks for the feedback. Not sure what you mean with "doesn't work for 0 or 1 cases"; but either way you have a nice solution from simoco, and maybe you can learn something from my use of match, index and iferror that can come in handy at some future time.

Comment: I just tried your edited solution. It completely works. Thank you so much. I wish I could accept 2 different beautiful goals at the same time. Your answer is longer but more easy to understand I think. I'll study it tomorrow. Accepted one is very abstracted for me. regards.